# Rails model - check if a DateTime object is within a day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model `ExchangeRates` which has a field `time` of type `DateTime`. I want to search for an exchange rate from the same day. I tried in the following manner:

```
  per = ExchangeRates.find_by(time: er.time.beginning_of_day..er.time.end_of_day)
```

However, this doesn't return an ExchangeRate object from the same day.
How could I correct this?

Comment: I often find `to_sql` to be helpful in cases like this -- it will show you the SQL that ActiveRecord translates call into. `ExchangeRates.find_by(time: er.time.beginning_of_day..er.time.end_of_day).to_sql`

Answer (score 0):

You may be better served attempting this with a `where` as follows:

```
per = ExchangeRates.where("time > ? AND time < ?", er.time.beginning_of_day, er.time.end_of_day)
```

This will translate your request directly into the SQL.  While it's much less ActiveRecord "ish" than I prefer, I've found no good way to do something simple that searches for ranges.

If you want something even cleaner you could consider monkey patching AR to support a `range` operation that effectively does something like this under the hood with the passed in hash.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

`per = ExchangeRates.where(time: er.time.beginning_of_day..er.time.end_of_day).first`

However, when i frequently use this type of query on a model, i prefer to duplicate data, and also use a date column.

Lets say, if i have a created_at column, i also add a created_on column. One has datetime type, letter has date type.